# Why does navigating chrome to a server I'm hosting automatically check for a robots.txt?

Tags: google-chrome

I was using python's `http.server` to serve a directory, and in the python logs I noticed that every time I opened the page, it also sent a GET to `http://<my_ip>:<the_port>/robots.txt?162939582`.

What gives? I assume this is for Google's data gathering, can I disable it?

Comment: [robots.txt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) is a file used to control URL access by bots that follow that standard. So, assuming Chrome was sending a GET request for that file (in place of GoogleBot itself or another search engine/bot), it would seem to imply that it was actually trying to respect your wishes (i.e. collecting a list of URLs to ignore, which you have specified as off-limits).

Comment: @Anaksunaman I knew what robots.txt was, but I'm curious why my web browser needs to check it? Pre-loading other pages on the website? Crawling the site to send data to google?

Comment: So after poking around at this, unfortunately, I can't seem to reproduce this issue. Using a fresh install of Chrome 90, Chrome developer tools, and two different web servers (Apache and `python -m http.server`) serving the same simple directory, the most I can see is an automatic request for `favicon.ico`.  I can't see any kind of automatic request for `robots.txt`. Unless I am mistaken, my guess would be that this request is being triggered by something other than Chrome.

Comment: @Anaksunaman Ah it was due to an extension which I was not aware would passively do anything, so that's good to know about. I can't believe I didn't think to check that earlier...

Comment: That makes sense. At least you have an answer now. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I had a chrome extension which was doing this. I found it by disabling all extensions and re-enabling them until I found the one responsible.